# How can I get a multiple selected values in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using drop down with multiple select name defined with `select[]`

How can I get selected values using jquery.

Comment: anything you have tried out??

Comment: var js={'code':$("[name=select] :selected")};

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The same way as any form element - use `val()`.

```
var selectedValues = $("#select").val();
```

With a multiple select you will see the value as a comma delimited string which can easily be posted for server-side processing or split into an array if required.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v22vh/)

Answer (score 7):

If someone wants **values** with **labels**. Then here is the solution:

```
var hexvalues = [];
var labelvalues = [];

$('#myMultiSelect :selected').each(function(i, selectedElement) {
 hexvalues[i] = $(selectedElement).val();
 labelvalues[i] = $(selectedElement).text();
});
```

Comment: exactly what i was searching for since last 2 days.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uLghB/)**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#select option:selected').each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
})​
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 var selectedItems= $('#ddlId option:selected');

selectedItems.each(function(obj,ind){
     $(obj).val() ;
} // or do with for (var i=0// normal js loop
```

Answer (score 2):

you should try this:

```
$("select[name^='select[']:eq(0)").val();
```

remember, that eq(0) is indicated what is the index of your element with the same name.